# What's the point of using more CPU threads than the number of CPU virtual cores when compressing with 7-Zip on Microsoft Windows?

Tags: windows, cpu, compression, 7-zip, threads

What's the point of using more CPU threads than the number of CPU virtual cores when compressing with 7-Zip on Microsoft Windows?

E.g. in the following screenshot, I have 6 CPU physical cores, 12 CPU virtual cores and 7-Zip proposes to use up to 24 threads:

[image]

Comment: Either Igor Pavlov has published this information or he hasn't. If he has, the information is available to you, if he hasn't, the information isn't available to us.

Comment: @music2myear Users can sometimes find some insight by themselves. Aren't we on "superuser" here?

Comment: If you're asking for "insight" you're looking for opinions, and yes, we are on Superuser, where opinions are not considered answers, and questions seeking opinions are not allowed.

Comment: @music2myear If you think "insight" means opinion, we're using a different dictionary.  Try https://www.google.com/search?q=insight+meaning&oq=insight+meaning I'm looking for technical facts.

Comment: Which takes us right back to my first comment: the technical facts will be contained within the documentation. Have you looked at or for the documentation?

Comment: @music2myear "the technical facts will be contained within the documentation." -> this is incorrect. Technical facts can be found in other places as well, such as fora.

Comment: StackExchange is not a fora.

Comment: A better question might have been "What's the point of using more CPU virtual cores than the number of CPU real cores?" As it stands, your question is "Why did someone not take the time to change a drop-menu to match reality?"

Comment: @DavidPostill I got lazy to enumerate other types of information sources such as Q&A websites and mailing lists. The point was that documentation doesn't contain all the knowledge about a program.

Comment: @Tetsujin the question is "What's the point of using more CPU threads than the number of CPU virtual cores when compressing with 7-Zip on Microsoft Windows?", which seems to already address your concern while focusing on number of threads instead of number of virtual cores (this makes the question more generic).

Comment: My concern is that you are taking an interface menu at face value. There's actually no point exceeding your actual core count for any task like this. Soon as you do you get diminishing returns, as each is considered as "important" as the rest, so scheduling starts to fight itself.

Comment: @Tetsujin the GUI was just a trigger for the question, but the question doesn't depends on the GUI, e.g. same question for CLI. I think your comment is a great answer, you're welcome to post it as such.

Answer (score 0):

After comments, I guess this becomes a frame challenge.

Let's assume that the software doesn't actively count cores to populate the drop menu & therefore we just have a 'bunch of numbers' in the drop menu [I might be wrong, but this seems the simplest explanation].

That leaves us with a more generic, 'what's the best number of cores to use for a parallel process?'

The answer to that is often debated, but my take on it, based on empiricism, is that the 'best' number of cores is your *real* core count. As in any parallel task  each thread has equal 'importance' then once you go above your real core count & into hyper-threading, you start to generate scheduling conflicts within the CPU management &, therefore, though you *may* actually increase overall throughput, you do it at diminishing returns.

A reasonably easy way to test this is using a VM for something very heavy like application compiling or video compression. By varying the number of cores allotted to the VM, you can quite quickly see how this 'ideal' is arrived at. [This assumes no other bottleneck; my tests were done on a pair of 6-core [real] Xeons, so 24 HT threads, 64GB RAM, 2 SSD drives to separate as much read/write as possible from the actual results]